# Stuck on a relatively easy probability problem

Tags: probability

Problem: In a class of 10 students 3 have studied everything (team A), 4 very well (team B), 2 moderately (team C) and one is unprepared (team D). From the 20 possible questions that might be asked during the exam, team A can answer all 20, team B can answer 16, team C can answer 10 and team D can answer 5. The exam contains 3 questions. what is the probabilty that a team D student will answer all 3 correctly.
This is part of a bigger question, but I am stuck here. I am sure I have seen this concept before, but right now I am confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry misread, thought unprepared meant they couldn't answer any.

Comment: Let's say 5 questions team D able to answer are question 1 to 5. The exam paper only contains 3 questions, then the problem becomes choose 3 questions from 20 that belongs to question 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  What is the chance that team D can answer the first question?  Now that you have used up one that team can answer, what is the chance the team can answer the next?  The third?  Since you are asking about getting them all right, you multiply the probabilities.

Comment: Are you implying P=(5/20)*(4/19)*(3/18)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton, I really appreciated not giving away the sollution, now I'll probably remember it!